# change application root context in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I've got an application that runs on

```
http://localhost:8080/templates-web
```

I want to change it to

```
http://localhost:8080/templates-ui
```

I've created folder `META-INF` and created there `context.xml` file.
The context of `context.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash='false' path="templates-ui"></Context>
```

But it does not work. It still runs on `templates-web`.

How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
<Context path="" docBase="myAPP">
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
<Context path="ROOT" docBase="ROOT">
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

And, add above to the  section in server.xml

Comment: I can make changes only in my application because tomcat is located on another machine.